# Showing Two Fields With Different Timeline in the Same Date Structure

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, foreign-keys, relational-database

In the project I am currently working on in my company, I would like to show sales related KPIs together with Customer Score metric on SQL / Tableau / BigQuery

The primary key is order id in both tables. However, order date and the date we measure Customer Score may be different. For example the the sales information for an order that is released in Feb 2020 will be aggregated in Feb 2020, however if the customer survey is made in March 2020, the Customer Score metric must be aggregated in March 2020. And what I would like to achieve in the relational database is [as follows:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2OXO.png)

Sales:

| Order ID | Order Date(m/d/yyyy) | Sales ($) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 1/1/2021 | 1000 |
| 1001 | 2/1/2021 | 2000 |
| 1002 | 3/1/2021 | 1500 |
| 1003 | 4/1/2021 | 1700 |
| 1004 | 5/1/2021 | 1800 |
| 1005 | 6/1/2021 | 900 |
| 1006 | 7/1/2021 | 1600 |
| 1007 | 8/1/2021 | 1900 |

Customer Score Table:

| Order ID | Customer Survey Date(m/d/yyyy) | Customer Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 3/1/2021 | 8 |
| 1001 | 3/1/2021 | 7 |
| 1002 | 4/1/2021 | 3 |
| 1003 | 6/1/2021 | 6 |
| 1004 | 6/1/2021 | 5 |
| 1005 | 7/1/2021 | 3 |
| 1006 | 9/1/2021 | 1 |
| 1007 | 8/1/2021 | 7 |

Expected Output:

| KPI | Jan-21 | Feb-21 | Mar-21 | Apr-21 | May-21 | June-21 | July-21 | Aug-21 | Sep-21 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sales($) | 1000 | 2000 | 1500 | 1700 | 1800 | 900 | 1600 | 1900 |  |
| AVG Customer Score |  |  | 7.5 | 3 |  | 5.5 | 3 | 7 | 1 |

I couldn't find a way to do this, because order date and survey date may/may not be the same.

For sample data and expected output, [click here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1up36VRW8fzbStPlQytf-HfKfujjUtYH9/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.  Sample data as *text* tables or DDL statements are preferred.

Comment: Dear @GordonLinoff , added. Is it OK, I can review if necessary. Many thanks for your reply.

Comment: Most people here want sample data as formatted text, not as images (or, even worse, links to images.) Make it easy to assist you!

Comment: Dear friend @jarlh I have added an Excel file attached above, is it OK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want to do is aggregate your results to the month (KPI) first before joining, as opposed to joining on the ORDER_ID

For example:

```
with order_month as (
  select date_trunc(order_date, MONTH) as KPI, sum(sales) as sales
  from `testing.sales`
  group by 1
  ),
  customer_score_month as (
  select date_trunc(customer_survey_date, MONTH) as KPI, avg(customer_score) as avg_customer_score
  from `testing.customer_score`
  group by 1
  )
  select coalesce(order_month.KPI,customer_score_month.KPI) as KPI, sales, avg_customer_score 
  from order_month
  full outer join customer_score_month
  on order_month.KPI = customer_score_month.KPI
  order by 1 asc
```

Here, we aggregate the total sales for each month based on the order date, then we aggregate the average customer score for each month based on the date the score was submitted. Now we can join these two on the month value.

This results in a table like this:

| KPI | sales | avg_customer_score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 1000 | null |
| 2021-02-01 | 2000 | null |
| 2021-03-01 | 1500 | 7.5 |
| 2021-04-01 | 1700 | 3.0 |
| 2021-05-01 | 1800 | null |
| 2021-06-01 | 900 | 5.5 |
| 2021-07-01 | 1600 | 3.0 |
| 2021-08-01 | 1900 | 7.0 |
| 2021-09-01 | null | 1.0 |

You can pivot the results of this table in Tableau, or leverage a case statement to pull out each month into its own column - I can elaborate more if that will be helpful

Comment: Dear Leigha you are the best. It worked like magic! Thank you so much. Can you please elaborate further regarding making each month into its own column on SQL?